# Add Key to an Array if Element Exist using Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a JSON object that has fields like subject1,subject2,subject3 with string arrays as value.

If any search element exist inside string arrays that is assigned to fields subject1,subject2,subject3  then I need to add the key or that field from Json Object to an existing array (myArray),

```
    %dw 2.0
    var myArray = [];
    var subjects = {
    "subject1" = ["sectionA", "sectionB", "sectionC"],
    "subject2" = ["sectionB", "sectionD", "sectionE"],
    "subject3" = ["sectionC", "sectionF", "sectionG"],
    }
    
    fun getSubjects(section) = mapping mapObject ((value, key, index) ->
       if(value contains key) myArray << key
       else myArray 
    )

    ---

    {
      "subjects" : getSubjects(var.section) // var.section = sectionA
    }
```

But I'm getting this error "Cannot coerce Array to Object". Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey @chakez! Could you please provide the content of var.section? Also, if you could add an input example and the expected output? Thank you.

Comment: what o/p you want here, explain it in more detail like what type of o/p you need?

Comment: @chakez you can't do this because all of the data types are immutable in dataweave. You'll have to recursively do this, essentially creating a new array each time with the updated contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you were trying to do; because data is immutable in dataweave you have to use something like reduce if you want to iterate a collection while changing something like an array's content.

```
%dw 2.0

var subjects = {
    "subject1": ["sectionA", "sectionB", "sectionC"],
    "subject2": ["sectionB", "sectionD", "sectionE"],
    "subject3": ["sectionC", "sectionF", "sectionG"]
}

var section = "sectionA"

fun getSubjects(section) = subjects pluck $$ reduce ((subject, myArray=[]) ->
    if (subjects[subject] contains section) myArray << subject
    else myArray
)

---
{
    subjects: getSubjects(section)
}
```

Yields:

```json
{
  subjects: [
    "subject1"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do this is as below where we are sending variable and the string that need to match

```
%dw 2.0
var myArray = []
var subjects = {
"subject1" : ["sectionA", "sectionB", "sectionC"],
"subject2" : ["sectionA", "sectionD", "sectionE"],
"subject3" : ["sectionC", "sectionF", "sectionG"],
 }
 
fun adding(inputarray,matchingkey)= flatten(inputarray mapObject ((value, key) -> 
 (("myArray"): (myArray ++ [key])) if ((value) contains matchingkey) 
 ) pluck $)
 
---
 
adding(subjects,"sectionC")
```

**Output is:**

```
[
  "subject1", 
  "subject3"
]
```